# ionic lib update command line not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

i'm using :

```
$ionic lib update
you sure you want to replace D:\Projects\cda-volunteer\www\lib\ionic with an updated version of Ionic? (yes/no): yes 
    Unable to receive version data
```

ionic info :

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7 
ios-deploy version: Not installed 
ios-sim version: Not installed 
OS: Windows 8.1 
Node Version: v6.9.1 
Xcode version: Not installed
```

> ionic --version : 
>   2.2.1

```
ionic lib :
Local Ionic version: 1.2.4
```

what should i do ?

Comment: what does `ionic info` say?

Comment: **ionic info** :
ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed

**ionic --version** : 2.2.1

**ionic lib** : Local Ionic version: 1.2.4

Comment: Kindly note that i'am using ionic 1 not ionic 2 , so i did this command before : npm install -g ionic : it gives me ionic v2.2.1 . so i don't know if it's mean ionic 2

Comment: ionic lib update was when they used bower..so it doesnt work now

Comment: You can still create ionic1 project with the latest ionic cli..

Answer (score 0):

You have a higher version of `ionic-cli`

`ionic lib update` no longer works. Ionic is now using npm

Try
`npm install ionic-app-lib --save`

Verify which version is required for your project.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of the Ionic CLI `ionic lib update` is no longer supported. Some ways you can go about updating:

Use `npm install ionic-angular --save` within your project directory.

To upgrade the version of the libraries manually within your project update the `package.json` with the latest:

`"ionic-angular": "2.0.1"` would become `"ionic-angular": "2.1.0"` then you can `npm update`.

Here's an example of the Ionic Conference's updated `package.json` when updating from 2.0.1 to 2.1.0:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/pull/362/files

Comment: You are refering to Ionic2 app. Op is refering to ionic 1 app

Answer (score 0):

i download this version 1.3.2 from this url : 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.3.2
and then i replace my lib ionic inside my project by the release folder downloaded